# Toggle divs and Mootools - same script and style but different effect

Tags: javascript, mootools, show-hide, slidetoggle, togglebutton

I'm stuck probably with easy thing, but spent two days without finding any solution. Generaly I have mootools script writen for my theme, which works fine with some divs.  **[HERE](http://exthemes.zz.mu/index.php/forum/welcome-mat/1-welcome-to-kunena)** is the link to problem.

When you logged in (user:demo, pass:demo) you will see, under the message, buttons: **Who Said Thank You**, **Attachments** and very long button **COM_KUNENA_BUTTON_QUICK_REPLY_reply** (the name is not important, just missed lang strings).

So when you click on **Who Said Thank You** or **Attachments** buttons, hidden div will appear (or close). The same should happen with the long button and show Quick Reply form below the message (which is already displayed). And here is the thing I don't know how to fix. Buttons are wrapped in div with class that trigger the script. Unfortunately one is working incorrectly.

I checked **[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x8E8g/)** (only part of script included with **divs used on my website**) and can't reproduce the problem as works perfectly)

please help

Comment: @Sergio Yes, but using `onClick="return false; .style.display = 'block'` which do the job, but would do better using MooTools implemented in Joomla and in this code http://jsfiddle.net/AgpbL/ line started with `var qreply = $$('.quick-reply');`

Comment: Updated this answer also, you can add this code inside the DOMready function on the exthemes1.js file

Comment: I think also `.reveal()` is more alike the slide/fade in function you have in other divs instead of just `display:block;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
document.getElements('a[data-target^="#quick-reply"]').addEvent('click', function(ev){ 
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    this.reveal(); 
});
```

And remove the `onClick="return false; .style.display = 'block'` inside the html.

Comment: Thank you again Sergio! This was realy helpfull, especialy your answer for my [previous question]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552790/addclass-converting-from-jquery-to-mootools that it doesn't have to be a conflict but just a complex page. You are amazing :)

Comment: @Ireek, you're welcome. I like Mootools so I fight a bit extra for those questions :) If you want you can upvote my answer also ;)

Comment: Sure, you deserve for up!