# addClass converting from jQuery to MooTools

Tags: jquery, mootools, addclass

I have Kunena forum template for Joomla that use MooTools 1.4. I integrated in this theme bootstrap tooltip functionality and added MooTools addClass to trigger tooltips in some classes. I checked MooTools doc's and the code should looks like below:

```
$$('h3 a, .tk-page-header h1 .tk-latestpost a, .tk-topic-title a, .tk-topic-info a, .tk-preview-avatar a, .tk-social-icons a, .kpost-user-icons a, .kicon-profile, .tk-user-info-body li a, span.kkarma-plus, span.kkarma-minus, .btnImage').addClass(' hasTooltip');
```

Above code can be seen on http://jsfiddle.net/AgpbL/ (scroll to the bottom)

Unfortunately it doesn't work, so I created the following jQuery script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(a){
   a("h3 a, .tk-page-header h1 .tk-latestpost a, .tk-topic-title a, .tk-topic-info a, .tk-preview-avatar a, .tk-social-icons a, .kpost-user-icons a, .kicon-profile, .tk-user-info-body li a, span.kkarma-plus, span.kkarma-minus, .btnImage").addClass(" hasTooltip");   
});
(jQuery);
```

and it works very well itself. Unfortunately it cause a conflict with MooTools so I went back to MooTools and (after searching stackoverflow) I created another code:

```
$$('h3 a, .tk-page-header h1 .tk-latestpost a, .tk-topic-title a, .tk-topic-info a, .tk-preview-avatar a, .tk-social-icons a, .kpost-user-icons a, .kicon-profile, .tk-user-info-body li a, span.kkarma-plus, span.kkarma-minus, .btnImage').addEvents({
  'mouseenter': function() { $(this).addClass(' hasTooltip'); },
  'mouseleave': function() { $(this).removeClass(' hasTooltip'); }
});
```

and no effect again.

Comparing basic `myElement.addClass(className);` MooTools to `.addClass( className )` jQuery I couldn't find big differences but obviously something is wrong I'm not able to understand.

Any help or pointing to elsewhere  is much appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? I created a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/c66e6/) of your fiddle, and it quite clearly shows that class _is_ added. `$$` method returns a collection of Elements, which basically has all the methods of Element applicable, and `addClass` is certainly one of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately it's not. You can check on my demo site where just addedd your code. Tooltip should appear when hover "Welcome Mat" link, but it's not http://exthemes.zz.mu/index.php/forum/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure were your conflict with jQuery is but you can use Mootools [**.getElements()**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getElements) instead of `$$` and you don't need to wrap `this` like in jQuery. Try this:

```
document.getElements('h3 a, .tk-page-header h1 .tk-latestpost a, .tk-topic-title a, .tk-topic-info a, .tk-preview-avatar a, .tk-social-icons a, .kpost-user-icons a, .kicon-profile, .tk-user-info-body li a, span.kkarma-plus, span.kkarma-minus, .btnImage').addEvents({
  'mouseenter': function() { this.addClass('hasTooltip');},
  'mouseleave': function() { this.removeClass('hasTooltip');}
});
```

EDIT:
I see the code I suggested is online and working. The problem, and I understood now, is that class is useless unless its there from DOM ready because jQuery want's to include it in tooltips. This takes me to the next question: Is this what you want?
[image]

If what you want is to have a tooltip in all those elements then you need to add the class before jQuery attached tooltip to those elements. So ignore the code above and use:

```
document.getElements('h3 a, .tk-page-header h1 .tk-latestpost a, .tk-topic-title a, .tk-topic-info a, .tk-preview-avatar a, .tk-social-icons a, .kpost-user-icons a, .kicon-profile, .tk-user-info-body li a, span.kkarma-plus, span.kkarma-minus, .btnImage').addClass('hasTooltip');
```

Use this before this code `jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"container": false});` which seems to be in the head of the index page.

I don't think you have framework conflicts here, just a complex page with nice gadgets to get lost in :)

Comment: Thanks, but neither this one. I thought when I will use one framework, everything should be easier. Seems like simple things are more difficult to achieve. Probably will have to find workaround

Comment: jQuery is used by Joomla generaly and Bootstrap (I implemented to make this theme mobile ready) tooltips plugins. My forum theme is based on latest Mootools (included in Joomla aswell). So I thought if Mootools can't handle class adding, jQuery will do. And it does (but causing conflict with Mootools like not loading forum editor, etc). This is strange, relly...

Comment: @Ireek, I saw your link on the comments now. Went there and pasted my code/answer on the console and it worked great. Add and remove class. What do you think is not working? What should happen?

Comment: To be honest I have no clue. Addedd your code to `exthemes1.js` and still no tooltips when hover over ie. editor emoticons (when creating new topics) or over the links on main page. Honestly don't know...

Comment: Thanks, sleep well :)

Comment: Perfect (updated) answer! Thank you so much for your time and effort. Really apreciated :)